# Where are all of the serapede eggs ?

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

In the archives, we are tasked with killing all of the eggs before they hatch... Seeing as I do NOT want to find out what happens when they hatch, where are all of those 10 eggs ? I have only found 9... Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eggs randomize their positions so it's hard to say. I had to reload the checkpoint before I could find all 10. Checking guides on youtube will also help you out.

Answer (score 2):

The eggs are randomly spawned, so I can't tell you exactly where your missing eggs may be.  However, I can give you some tips:

- **Check Down Low** - I've had the eggs spawn down in holes in the center rooms.
- **Check the Ceiling** - There always seems to be a couple of egg stacks stuck up in the corner of rooms, so make sure you look around high.

If all else fails, you can always just reload the previous checkpoint and the egg spawns will change.

Answer (score 0):

Came here for help, too, but actually found them on my own. Just look around... I found the last one in the corner of the weapons room... I never thought to look in there after finding ammo and stuff... They are on the ceilings and sometimes in the glowing hole, but they are always in sight.